# matching content of a file

Tags: javascript, html

I´m having a problem with a javascript function.
The idea is read the content of a file with javascript. Everything is working ok, I can see the content of the file, just now I want to organize the content.

And what I meant with organize is:

My file have a lot of strings, for example: tel#01234567#tel tel#01456789#tel dept#level1#dept dept#level4#dept.....

And everything is a line of strings, and at the end is that all what I see...

My goal is, when I read the file, at the end it have to show something like this:

Tel:  01234567
      01456789

Dept: Level1
      Level2

There is a way to have something like that?

```
function loaded(evt)
  {
    // Obtain the read file data    
    var fileString = evt.target.result;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = fileString;
  }
```

Comment: And what you meant with organize was actually "parse" and then it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: There are various string functions that could be used such as [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

So basically your file has attributes and data for the respective attribute surrounded by the attribute name + #?

The easiest thing would be to have the file in a common format for data, e.q. JSON. Then you could just use the attributes from the object you get by JSON.parse();

However, if you cannot change the file structure you will have to programm something that splits your string into the desired parts and creates an object out of the attributes to work with.

For the string you presented you could do one string.split(" ") to get every attribute singled out, resulting in an array like this:

```
Array [ "tel#01234567#tel", "tel#01456789#tel", "dept#level1#dept", "dept#level4#dept" ]
```

Afterwards you can iterate over the array and string.split("#") again for each element which gives you this:

```
array[0].split("#");
Array [ "tel", "01234567", "tel" ]
```

Then you can use the first index of the array as attribute name and the second one as its data. You could put that into an object and afterwards refer from the attribute straight to the data:

```
var string = "tel#01234567#tel tel#01456789#tel dept#level1#dept dept#level4#dept";
var array = string.split(" ");
var dataObject = {};

for(var i in array){
    var element = array[i].split("#");
    if(dataObject.hasOwnProperty(element[0])){
        dataObject[element[0]].push(element[1]);
    }else{
        dataObject[element[0]] = [element[1]];
    }
}
```

In the end you have an object that has all the attributes as its properties and the corresponding data stored in an array for each property. With that you should be able to work right? :)

Answer (score -1):

When you read the file in you could use JS split to separate the content based on the delimiters.

Check it out here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: This is just a notch better than a link-only answer.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward though. I could always copy paste the definition of split

Comment: And what do you split this thing on?

Comment: The delimiter in your file seems to be the '#' symbol. So you can spit it up using that. If you give a sample file that you are using and what you want to do it would be better